# Jenkins: Not able to send email

Tags: selenium, email, jenkins, automation

I am using Jenkins 2.89.3 and setup Jenkins Editable Email Notification with triggers as Always.

Build run successfully but getting error in email sending. Console output is as:

```
Email was triggered for: Always

Sending email for trigger: Always

Sending email to: himanshu.jn48@gmail.com

Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds...

Connection error sending email, retrying once more in 10 seconds...

Failed after second try sending email

Finished: SUCCESS
```

I have received the email when I test the configuration by sending test e-mail.

I am attaching screenshot of SMTP Configuration.[link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR5Qv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your plugin setup, there may be more than one configuration for SMTP available in Jenkins. Make sure, they both have these email configuration properly set

```
Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "E-mail Notification
Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Extended E-mail Notification"
```

Based on the plugin you are using, make sure appropriate SMTP section is properly configured

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue with Jenkins not able to send email to the recepients. Tired the above solution...It works, Thanks for the solution.
Basically, we have to configure email settings under both the sections
Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "E-mail Notification
Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Extended E-mail Notification"